# webpack dll configuration not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to create dll configuration with webpack 4, but i keep getting:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
```

My configuration is very simple:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    vendor: ["react", "react-dom"]
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name]-manifest.dll.js",
    path: base.path.project("build"),
    library: "[name]",
    libraryTarget: "umd"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DllPlugin({
      name: "[name]",
      path: base.path.project("build/[name]-manifest.json"),
      context: base.path.src("app")
    })
  ]
};
```

In my development configuration I use the dllreferenceplugin.

```
new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
  context: base.path.src("app"),
  manifest: require("../build/vendor-manifest.json")
})
```

and of course i define externals in development configuration, because I don't want to include them again when building my development js file:

```
  externals: {
    react: "React",
    "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
  }
```

In my code I import React.

```
import * as React from "react";
```

But in the browser I keep getting React is not defined.

I have googled everything and have not found any solution to this problem?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `import React, { Component } from 'react';` myself. JSX wants react to be in scope.

Largely only see externals being used when making a library, like a npm module that other folks consume that uses React. React would be marked as an external in that package to avoid double including React in the local application *and* inside the module.

If this is your app build process, and not an npm module then should not be marking react as externals. Your bundle needs to include react. Marking react as externals excludes it from the bundle and makes it your responsibility to manually load React before the bundle is loaded.

> The externals configuration option provides a way of excluding
>   dependencies from the output bundles.

See the docs on webpack externals [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/).

Comment: Yes, the dll is bundling React, If I remove them from external, then there is no point in using dll as fare as I understand, because both the vendors.js bundle react, and also my application.js!

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly you need to import from the `path/to/dll` instead of from `node_modules` which is where `import React from 'react'` would be resolving to? Have not used `webpack.DllReferencePlugin`. Also see in the dll docs "This plugin is used in a __separate webpack config exclusively to create a dll-only-bundle__", reads like configs should not be combined. https://webpack.js.org/plugins/dll-plugin/

Comment: In the browser it should get the React from the global env, like when you define script src="cdn...react", my code will find react and render it normally, but the dll is somehow not sharing React! I'm creating this separat dll so I don't need to keep compiling most of the node_modules in the development env. I hope you understand. That's what dll is used for, to speed up the compiling of my large application.

Comment: Sounds like you're after caching. Canonical way to go about that with webpack is https://github.com/mzgoddard/hard-source-webpack-plugin. Use it myself here: https://github.com/buildbreakdo/aws-lambda-starter-kit/blob/master/webpack.config.js

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove the external property from your app webpack config file.Also, Include the dll file in your index.html file.

I was also facing the same issue, because I was using both dllReference plugin and external at the same time.